# unable to load ansible playbook to a docker host (host unreachable)

Tags: docker, ansible

im trying to : `ansible-playbook install_docker.yml`

and keep getting the following error:

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************

fatal: [172.17.0.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", "unreachable": true}
```

my playbook looks like this

```
---

- hosts: all

vars:

docker_opts: >

  - "H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

  - "H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"

remote_user: root

roles:

 - angstwad.docker.ubuntu
```

im providing the docker host ip by copying the ip using:

```
docker inspect apacheweb1 | grep IPAddress
```

how can i reach the docker host?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?